# wpf how to send string or info on anther page or window or usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, visual-studio

i have big problem visual studio wpf , when i try to send any string it doesn't work
i tried to write `public string str { set; get; }` This problem has been stuck with it for a long time, I tried a lot to use crooked methods, but the program or project crashes.

im using visual studio wpf c#

thank you for answer

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Info.Content = "Hello world";
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Frame.Content = new Page1();
        }

        private void button2_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Info.Content = "Label";
        }

        private void button1_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Info.Content = "Label";
        }
    }
```

here Page class

```
public partial class Page1 : Page
    {
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
            mw.Info.Content = "Test Public";
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks mate finally its work (But I don't understand the code)

Comment: Hi,@ATM.What to do here is to find and use the current window via [Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)instead of creating a new one.

Comment: In WPF, consider to use the [MVVM pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern) and use [Bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-6.0) instead of setting values of named controls. The earlier you adapt to that way of programming WPF, the better for you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update Page1's button1_MouseEnter code to:

```
private void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow mw = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>().First();

    mw.Info.Content = "Test Public";
}
```

or

```
private void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow mw = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;

    mw.Info.Content = "Test Public";
}
```